# azure cosmos db - SQL api Dynamic sorting based on the values in documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using Cosmos DB + SQL api, where my data (millions of records) in the collection is as shown below, I want to write a query where I should get data from brand "lit" first and then from "pil", any suggestion on the efficient ways of achieving this? Please note different users in my system have different order preference of seeing the data. g: one user may want "lit" first, other users may want "pil" first.

**Sample data set:**
[
{
"brand": "appl",
"model": "test2",
"image": "url2"
},
{
"brand": "lit",
"model": "test1",
"image": "url1"
},
{
"brand": "lit",
"model": "test3",
"image": "url3"
},
{
"brand": "pil",
"model": "test4",
"image": "url4"
},
{
"brand": "lit",
"model": "test5",
"image": "url5"
}
]